# Login.aspx not using expected SQL Membership Provider database

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, security, sqlmembershipprovider

Any help appreciated!

What is needed so that the `Login.aspx` page is using the database as shown through the `MyDatabaseConnection`

1. I created an ASP.NET Web Forms application
2. Configured SQL Server Membership Provider (or so I thought) in the main `web.config`.

   Added `MyDatabaseConnection`:

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="DefaultConnection" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-VideoProject-20131115191757;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-VideoProject-20131115191757.mdf"/>
       <add name="MyDatabaseConnection" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=videolibrary;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\videolibrary.mdf"/>
   </connectionStrings>
   ```

   `MyDatabaseConnection` points to the desired database that already has the tables, users and passwords configured (not by me).

   ```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/"/>
   </authentication>

   ...

   <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
       <providers>
           <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MyDatabaseConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
       </providers>
   </membership>
   ```
3. Created `Secure.aspx` in `Secure` folder.
4. Created `web.config` in the `Secure` folder with

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
       <system.web>
           <authorization>
               <deny users="?" />
           </authorization>
       </system.web>
   </configuration>
   ```
5. Using Project\ASP.NET Configuration, I added a user `TestAccount`.
6. Added a link in the application that points to `Secure.aspx`.

When debugging the application, I select the link that points to `Secure.aspx`. Through `login.aspx`, I can login as `TestAccount` and the `Secure.aspx` page is displayed as expected.

When I use a login user/password from the `MyDatabaseConnection` database, it fails. That is, login is unsuccessful. It is not looking at this database but I do not know what else  is needed for the `login.aspx` page to use it?

After this, I tried adding `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` in the following of the main `web.config`:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name ="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="MyDatabaseConnection"
             applicationName="/" />
            <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MyDatabaseConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

but received the following error immediately after trying to login:

> Parser Error Message: The entry 'AspNetSqlMembershipProvider' has already been added.
>   Source Error:
>   Line 31:     
>   Line 32:       
>   Line 33:         
>   Line 34:              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
>   Line 35:              connectionStringName="MyDatabaseConnection"

I searched for `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` elsewhere (since said already used) within the web.config and did not see it. Note: Unfortunately, I could not use code formatting adequately due to issues using it.

Thanks,

Buck

Comment: try adding `<Clear/>` as first attribute after `<Providers>` tag

Comment: Closer and thanks. It gets rid of the "Parser Error Message: The entry 'AspNetSqlMembershipProvider' has already been added." with the SQLMembershipProvider statement added. I also tried it without the SQLMembershipProvider statement. In both cases, it is still not looking at the right database. My login "Test Account" which is from the other database is working. Logins from the expected database are not.